# Programmatically changing the Keyboard Input Language

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I have to change input keyboard language for particular my application only not for whole device. I don't want to change local only change to input keyboard language.

I'm able to change whole device input keyboard language but want only for my application only.

I review many things on google ,find solutions but din't works for me it will be great if anyone can help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many language in your keyboard then select default language and use particular keyboard.
for an ex Open Gboard add multiple languages and use it